# Работа с бинарными файлами в Qt

Tags: c++, алгоритм, qt, файлы, qt5

Я пишу программму-шифровщик. Ее суть в том, что она обрабатывает двоичные данные через операцию XOR. И вот проблема: я должен открыть любой файл (т. е. расширение не важно) и обработать его побитно. Как открыть файл, я узнал, а вот как его обработать? Может, использовать QByteArray? Сейчас мне нужно просто узнать, единица ли в массиве или ноль, а затем в зависимости от пароля применить нужное значение и сохранить файл.

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Comment: Не нужно вам знать единица там или ноль, XOR работает на байтах ровно так же, как на битах.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, мне нужно применять XOR вручную, т. е. побитово.

Comment: Данные в файле все равно лежат в байтах, применяйте побайтово

Comment: Ну так итерируйтесь одновременно по ключу и по `QByteArray`, и ксорьте их, пока не кончится последний.

Comment: Совершенно необязательно извлекать каждый бит из байта, чтобы применить к нему `xor`. Например, `55 xor 22 = 33` (`110111 xor 10110 = 100001`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вы хотите пользоваться сугубо Qt, то Вам подойдёт 
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbitarray.html .